# Braintree peer-to-peer iOS

Tags: ios, paypal, p2p, braintree

I would like to include Paypal as a peer-to-peer options to pay back friends in my iPhone app.
However, when I search online for Paypal iOS, it says that I should use Braintree now.

It's pretty easy to use and include in the application.

But I don't know if and how Braintree handles peer-to-peer.
I suppose it should, since Paypal doesn't approve Adaptive Payments anymore.

> Adaptive Payments is now a limited release product. It is restricted
>   to select partners for approved use cases and should not be used for
>   new integrations without guidance from PayPal.

So how to include peer-to-peer in my application now?

Answer (score 1):

I came across your question, because I have the same issue. I was on the right track using Adaptive Payments, and then came back to work on it to see that lots of things had changed. Also, both the sender and the receiver have to sign up for PayPal to make peer-to-peer payments.

I switched to using Braintree - [here's](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/start/hello-client/ios/v4) their iOS setup page.

From my understanding, you just have to manage payments between the two parties. The payer would pay you, and then you would in turn pay the payee.

For example, A --> Your App --> B.

I'm working on the same thing, so when I make some headway, I'll come back here. Otherwise, if this doesn't work, Stripe it is!

Good luck!

Comment: Did you get any hope to implement peer-to-peer payments using PayPal?

Comment: I left this project where it is for now, since I was unable to configure the backend work. I was trying to accomplish this using only their API and mobile code. I'm pretty sure it's possible, once you comb through the docs. Lastly, their engineers are really good at getting back to you with questions, I'd definitely recommend writing them with questions. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

After some extensive googling, I managed to find the answer [here : setting-payee](https://www.paypal-engineering.com/2017/01/03/setting-payee/)

You need to add new "payee" object in "transactions" array along with "amount" and "description".